# AG-Grid: Translate headerName with ngx-translate (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

We are using Angular to visualise an AG grid. We want the headers of the ag grid to be translated in the language of the user.

Ag grid code:

```html
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-material" [rowData]="productionOrders">
  <ag-grid-column [headerName]="'ORDERS.GRID.EntryCode' | translate" field="entry"></ag-grid-column>
  <ag-grid-column [headerName]="ORDERS.GRID.EntryDescription" field="entryDescription"></ag-grid-column>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

The same way we can translate a value on our html page itself:

```html
<span>{{ 'ORDERS.Status' | translate}}</span>
```

I noticed, when the translations are being loaded, ag grid does not notice when the translations are loaded. The value on the html page itself however gets translated.

Extra info: The translate pipe of ngx-translate is an "impure" pipe, which means its value can change (eg. when all translations are loaded)

The same way, when using a headerName without a translation, it does not get updated:

Ag grid code:

```html
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-material" [rowData]="productionOrders">
  <ag-grid-column [headerName]="bindedString" field="entry"></ag-grid-column>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```js
this.lazyString = 'test-1';
setTimeout(() => {
  this.lazyString = 'test-2';
}, 3000);
```

The header name is never updated to "test-2"

Comment: Did you import the "translate" pipe to the moudle.ts?if you are not sure you can look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ara2cQ4IQxA

Comment: Yes, i'm using the translate pipe on the same page as well, so that should be okay.

Answer (score 6):

## demo.component.html

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-material" [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [pagination]="true">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

## demo.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef, GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.scss']
})
export class DemoComponent {
  private gridApi: GridApi = null;

  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { headerName: "Code", field: 'code', sortable: true, resizable: true, headerValueGetter: this.localizeHeader.bind(this) },
    { headerName: 'Version', field: 'version', sortable: true, resizable: true, headerValueGetter: this.localizeHeader.bind(this) },
    { headerName: 'IsEnabled', field: 'isEnabled', sortable: true, resizable: true, headerValueGetter: this.localizeHeader.bind(this) }
  ];

  public rowData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
    })
  }

  public onGridReady(parameters: any): void {
    this.gridApi = parameters.api;
  }

  public localizeHeader(parameters: ICellRendererParams): string {
    let headerIdentifier = parameters.colDef.field;
    return this.translateService.instant(headerIdentifier);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> [**Header Value Getters**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#header-value-getters)
>
> Use `headerValueGetter` instead of `colDef.headerName` to allow dynamic header names.

```
private translator: TranslateService;
...
colDef.headerValueGetter : this.localizeHeader.bind(this)
....
localizeHeader(params){
    let headerIdentifier = params.colDef.field; // params.column.getColId();
    this.translator.get(headerIdentifier).map((res: string) => {
        return res;
    });
}
```

[Sample from doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-columns/#column-tool-panel-example)

```
{ 
    headerName: "Country", 
    field: "country", 
    width: 120, 
    enableRowGroup: true, 
    enablePivot: true, 
    headerValueGetter: countryHeaderValueGetter 
},

function countryHeaderValueGetter(params) {
    switch (params.location) {
        case 'csv': return 'CSV Country';
        case 'clipboard': return 'CLIP Country';
        case 'toolPanel': return 'TP Country';
        case 'columnDrop': return 'CD Country';
        case 'header': return 'H Country';
        default: return 'Should never happen!';
    }
}
```

Comment: It(s a little bit different the way I use it. I use ag grid in the html markdown.
`<ag-grid-column headerName="ORDERS.GRID.EntryDescription" [headerValueGetter]="translateHeaderValue" field="entryDescription"></ag-grid-column>`


So in typescript it is like this
`translateHeaderValue(params) {
  params.context.translateService.get(params.colDef.headerName).pipe(map((res: string) => {
 console.log(res);
 return res;
  }));
}`


But my console log 'res' never gets hit
Remark: I need to use the pipe in front of map, otherwise i'm havind an error map is not a function.

Comment: same problem here, it seems as the translator method is async the response callback never gets kicked. Did someone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the solution of TurboYang with async translation loading just add this:

```
  private destroy = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private toastService: ToastService, private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.onLangChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(() => {
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
    });
    translate.onDefaultLangChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(() => {
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy.next();
    this.destroy.complete();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Function in Service

```
  getTr(key: string) {
    return this.translate.instant(key);
  }
```

Usage in ColumnDefs

```
  {
    field: 'name', headerName: this.trService.getTr('NAME')
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution, which worked for me from the above references

```
columDef = [
               {
                  field: 'firstname',
                  headerValueGetter: () => translate.instant('fname') // fname is the translation key
               },
               {
                   field: 'lastname',
                   headerValueGetter: () => translate.instant('lname')
               },
           ]
 
 ngOnInit() 
 {
   this.translate.onLangChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(() => {
         this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
   });
  }
```