# How to translate ag grid header using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ngx-translate

I have an AG-GRID in my application, and I need to translate the header.
I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629693/ag-grid-translate-headername-with-ngx-translate-angular) but it didn't work, it's sad there is no method such refreshHeader()

I was wonderwing how to tranlsate header from ag grid

**HTML**

```
 <ag-grid-angular #grid class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="dataSource"
                       rowSelection=single domLayout=autoHeight [pagination]="true"
                       [context]="context" [paginationPageSize]=15 
                       [columnDefs]="columns" 
                       [defaultColDef]="defaultColumnDef">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS**

```
constructor(private translationService: TranslationService) {}
@ViewChild('grid') dataGrid?: AgGridAngular;
this.columns = [
      { headerName: 'teste', field:'type', sortable: true },
      { headerName: 'idtca'.toUpperCase(), field: 'idtca', sortable: true},
      { headerName: 'Raison', field: 'raison', sortable: true},
   
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
this.columns = [
    { headerValueGetter: this.headerTranslation('teste'), field:'type', sortable: true },
    { headerValueGetter: this.headerTranslation('Raison'), field: 'raison', sortable: true},
];
```

Then

```
headerTranslation(translateKey: string) {
  return () => this.translate.instant(translateKey);
}
```

You will need translation keys 'teste', 'Raison' and so on in your set of translations, but that is done in the standard ngx-translate way.

Comment: it did work but I had to a headerrefresh after every change language. Thanks you